# Python print first three characters of string in list using a for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, iteration

I am currently trying to make a statement that will print out the first three characters of every string in a list using a for loop.

```
for char in lst:
if len(char) == 3:
    print(char)
```

Comment: OK! Do you have a question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try something like this...

```
my_strings = ['aaaaaa', 'bbbb', 'ccc']

for el in my_strings:
    print el[:3]
```

It will `print` out all the first three characters of all the strings in the `list`, or, as done by the code, it will slice each string from index `0` all the way to, but not including, index `3`, then `print`ing the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python string slicing

```
my_list = ['answer', 'test', 'duh']
for string in my_list:
  print(string[:3])
```